# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 for user defined type

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++14

While attempting to test a Graph ADT I made from scratch, the compilation fails with

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: 
"Graph<Region>::order()", referenced from:
creates_a_connected_graph_graph_Test::TestBody() in graph.test.cpp.o
```

I have looked around on SO for solutions, but most of them point to a definition being different from an implementation (header vs .cpp), or are case-specific. I am brand new with C++ thus I have little idea how to proceed with this.

Here is the faulty code:

`Graph.h`

```
template <class E>
class Graph {
public:
  Graph<E>(std::vector<std::pair<string, std::shared_ptr<E>>> nodes, std::vector<std::pair<string, string>> edges);
  std::size_t order();
  // ...
private:
  const std::unordered_map<string, std::pair<std::shared_ptr<E>, short>> m_nodes;
  // ...
}
```

`Graph.cpp`

```
template <class E>
Graph<E>::Graph(
  std::vector<std::pair<string, std::shared_ptr<E>>> nodes,
  std::vector<std::pair<string, string>> edges) {
    for(const auto& node : nodes){
      addNode(std::get<0>(node), std::get<1>(node));
    }
    for(const auto& edge : edges){
      addEdge(std::get<0>(edge), std::get<1>(edge));
    }
};

/**
 * Returns the number of nodes in the Graph
 */
template <class E>
std::size_t Graph<E>::order() { return m_nodes.size(); };
```

`Graph.test.cpp`

```
TEST(creates_a_connected_graph, graph){
  using search_set = std::set<string>;
  using forest_map = std::unordered_map<string, std::pair<string, string>>;

  std::shared_ptr<Graph> g = loadGraph("./graph.json");
  const size_t order = g->order();
  const size_t dfs_order = algorithm::dfs<Region>(
    "r1",
    [](const string&, const search_set&, const forest_map&) -> bool { return true; }
  )(*g);
  ASSERT_EQ(order, dfs_order);
};
```

Environment:

- **OS:** MacOS 10.13.3
- **C++ Version Flag:** `-std=c++14`

Comment: Are you using xcode?

Comment: I do have xcode as well as all the developer tools installed. I use Atom + linter-clang however. My compilation is done via cmake, clang and g++.
The duplicate note seems to be accurate, I'll be looking into that solution.

Comment: The duplicate note was right! :) Cheers @liliscent & Niall